# How to add subscription to access a page in react native application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, in-app-purchase, stripe-payments, in-app-subscription

Good morning guys! I want to add a feature to my react native application that can only be accessed by subscribed users. But i don't know how to go about it. Also, there are a limited resources on this only. Can anyone please give me the steps involved, send me any useful article on it or even help me do it for a pay. I will really appreciate.

I do not have any code yet because i am new to react native. Please i need it for a project.

The project has three pages. "Home" "Payment" " Content". After clicking on a button in the home page, user will move to payment page. After making payment, user will then access the content page.

The users will not be able the content page until they make payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getItemFromStorage() {`AsyncStorage.getItem('paymentDone', (err, result) => { // result is boolean if(result) { that.props.navigation.push('ContentPage'); } else { // not allowed to go to Content } }); }`